# Object has a certain orbital period and is at perihelion or aphelion. What is it's orbital speed?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion, speed

I'm writing a simple game, but as you can already see I'm far from being a physicist of any kind. I have a system that calculates and draws orbit of a body with a given orbital speed and distance from parent body (Sun) at starting position. It's starting velocity vector is always perpendicular to the direction to the parent body, so at start it's always at perihelion or aphelion, depending on it's speed.

Calculating orbital period was easy though. Now I want an option to calculate and draw the orbit based on a given orbital period and make orbital speed adjust.

So what I know:

1. Object is at perihelion or aphelion.
2. Object is at certain $r$ distance from parent body.
3. Gravitational constant $G$.
4. Parent body mass $M$.
5. Object mass $m$ (irrelevant maybe).
6. Orbital period $T$.

What I need: orbital speed $v$.

My biggest issue is taking first point into consideration.
I know for circular orbit $$v = \sqrt{\frac{GM}{r}},$$ but that doesn't bring me any closer to solution.

Comment: There are various relevant equations at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_orbit & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_orbital_energy Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation I assume you just want to calculate simple orbits that pretend that the orbiting body is only affected by the gravity of the Sun, and not by the gravity of other bodies in the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume we can neglect the orbiting mass $m$ compared to the parent body mass $M$,
hence $m\ll M$.

In any Kepler orbit the orbital speed $v$, radius $r$
and semi-major axis $a$ are related by the [vis-viva equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vis-viva_equation#Equation):
$$v^2=GM\left(\frac{2}{r}-\frac{1}{a}\right) \tag{1}$$
This equation holds all the way along the orbit, not only
at perihelion and aphelion.

You also have [Kepler's 3rd law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion#Third_law_of_Kepler) relating the semi-major axis $a$
and orbital period $T$:
$$\frac{a^3}{T^2}=\frac{GM}{4\pi^2} \tag{2}$$

Now you can use both equations (1) and (2) and eliminate $a$ from them.
You will get an equation relating $v$, $r$ and $T$.
Then you can solve that equation for $v$.

Comment: Something interesting: this depends only only the semi-major axis $a$, and not the semi-minor axis or eccentricity.  In other words, you get exactly the same answer for a circle as for an ellipse, even an ellipse that's so narrow it's almost a line!  These are related to the _specific mechanical energy_ of the orbit, that is, the kinetic + potential energy divided by _m_.

The other value that determines the orbit is the _specific angular momentum_, which is simply the cross product of $r$ and $v$.

And for an ellipse, e = $(r_a - r_p)/(r_a + r_p)$.

Good luck with your game.

Comment: Can't find what's wrong with my math.
I set my starting velocity value and then calculate semi-major axis: 
$$
a=\frac{rGM}{2GM - rv^2}
$$
This is velocity equation solved for **a**. Then:
$$
T = 2\pi\sqrt{\frac{a^3}{GM}}
$$
Orbital period seem to be a correct value.
Then I take orbital period and run the math backwards.
$$
a=\sqrt[3]{\frac{T^2GM}{4\pi^2}}
$$
Then I calculate velocity back with:
$$
v = \sqrt{GM(\frac{2}{r} - \frac{1}{a})}
$$
The calculated velocity is wrong, but proper order of magnitude. Is my math wrong, or is it an issue with my code?

Comment: Can't edit previous comment as it's too long. NEVERMIND! It actually was a problem with my code, I forgot to put $ 4\pi^2$ in brackets. Thanks!